# struts2 iterator capturing particular values

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

Hi let me tell you i searched a lot but i could not find what i wanted

here is the scenario

there is table in my jsp which is being loaded through iterator  which is `ArrayList<Report>`

report has three attributes parameter,observation,designed

in the JSP i will show the first and third column values through iterator

```
<s:iterator value="ReportList" status="status" var="obj">
   <tr>
      <td><s:property value="%{#obj.parameter}" /></td>
      <td><s:textfield theme="simple" name="valOfSim" /></td>
      <td><s:property value="%{#obj.designed}" /></td>
   </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

> ```
> Parameter           observation                designed
> X                                                10
> y                                                11
> Z                                                12
> ```

now i have to capture the second value which has been entered  kindly help!

EDIT: my code

Let me explain first preload method will be called and the values will be prepopulated through `ArrayList<Obj>` and then the user will enter the value for observation then am capturing that through this

```
<td><s:textfield theme="simple" name="obj[%{#status.index}].observation" /></td>
```

after that a submit button will be there onclicking that submit method of action class will be called

which prints the value entered by user (here am getting NULL)

```
import mypro.web.utility.SpringServiceLocator;

public class myAction extends ActionSupport implements      
ModelDriven,SessionAware,ServletRequestAware,Preparable  {
private Map<String, Object> session;
private Model  model = new Model();

public void prepare()
{

            Obj obj = new Obj();
    Obj obj2 = new Obj();
    Obj obj3 = new Obj();

    obj.setDesigned("10");
    obj.setParameter("X");
    model.getReportList().add(obj1);


    obj.setDesigned("11");
    obj.setParameter("y");
    model.getReportList().add(obj2);

            obj.setDesigned("12");
    obj.setParameter("Z");
    model.getReportList().add(obj3);
   }



  public String preload()
   {

  return "success";
   }


  public String submit()
   {


  System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------  
  &&&&&&&&&:"+model.getReportList().size());
    for(Obj obj : model.getReportList)
    {
        System.out.println("the value is to be checked"+obj.getObservation());//value which will be entered by user
        System.out.println("the value is to be checked"+obj.getRefcode()); //value which was added in the prepare method
    }



        return "success";
      } 





       public Object getModel() {

    return model;
}
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: as you can see in the snippet am displaying the table in a jsp first and third colums are being fetched through ArrayList<obj> the second column which is blank will  be entered by user so i want to capture these values through the ArrayList<obj> i need to know how?

Comment: OK, so you'd like to submit all the fields all a time or for each line?

Comment: Have you tried creating an action with a getter/setter for a property called myCollection which is a collection... like an ArrayList? Then each property could be called myCollection in the form and you would think they would be added to myCollection, then in execute() you would do something to take the contents of myCollection and put them into your reports-objects.

Comment: As you can see, i've answered to obtain exactly that result :/ Have you tried ? Is it working ? Do you have any problem ?

Comment: @Andrea Ligios Thanks for the reply will let you know if its working

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<s:textfield theme="simple" name="valOfSim" />
```

to this:

```
<s:textfield theme="simple" name="obj[%{#status.index}].observation" value="" />
```

This will

1. bind your textfield to the `observation` field of the `obj` element;
2. preserve the line number;
3. setting the displayed value to empty (dunno why, but if this is what you want...)

This way, IF your Action has a `setter` for your obj element (and not only a getter), 
when you will submit the form containing your iterated elements, you will retrieve all the `observation` values inserted by the user in your `ArrayList<Obj>`...

Comment: hi andrea i tried your way its not working am getting null values,i do have getter and setter in my action but still not able to get any values

Comment: Are you calling the same Action after `submit`, or another one ? If another one, you need to declare a `List<obj>` on the second Action too (with at least the setter). And make sure that the `obj` class has setters too, like `setObservation`.

Comment: And please check the Interceptor Stack you are using for your Action(s): I've already seen people referencing ONE interceptor while believing to have added it to the whole stack...

Comment: Am using the default interceptor Stack,and as for as your previous questions are concerned am using the single action different method and i have the setter but still no luck getting Nulls

Comment: can you post some of your Action code ? It has to work... there is one error through the way :)

Comment: Ahhh ok i got it. Move ALL YOUR STUFF from `prepare()` to `preload()`. Prepare is invoked before EVERY method, then even before `submit()`, erasing all of your user-inputs from the jsp, due to re-initialitazion. OR, if you want to keep the initialization in prepare, move your submit method to another Action.

Comment: thanks for the tip about preparable i removed it and am using session and i made a small chane instead of var i used value  <s:textfield theme="simple" name="ReportList[%{#status.index}].observation" value="" />